# Find specific text with regex

Tags: regex, awk, sed

After retrieve json output with curl, I want to get a string between my json output. For example my json output :

$ curl -s https://myurl.com/api/json

{"server_timestamp": "2017-08-16T09:16:11+00:00", "version": "0.2", "api_status": "Normal"}

I want to get "0.2" from my json with awk or sed.

Comment: Did you have a try at this? Or are you just asking for someone to do your work for free?

Comment: just for free, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed` to retrieve the value for the key "version",

```
curl -s https://myurl.com/api/json | sed -r 's/^.*version": "([^"]+).*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

[***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/) is the right tool to parse/manipulate JSON data:

```
curl -s https://myurl.com/api/json | jq '.version'
```

The output:

```
"0.2"
```